# How can XUnit be configured to show just the method name in the Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit.net, test-explorer

When using `xunit.runner.visualstudio` version 2.0.1 in Visual Studio 2015, the names of the tests show up fully qualified.  Is there a way for the tests to show only the method name?

Consider the following test: -

```cs
namespace MySolution.Tests
{
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ClassUnderTest_WhenDefaultConstructorUsed_SomePropertyIsNotNull()
        {
            *... test code in here*
        }
    }
}
```

In the Test Explorer this shows as: -

```
MySolution.Tests.MyTestClass.ClassUnderTest_WhenDefaultConstructorUsed_SomePropertyIsNotNull
```

Using MSTest/VSTest this will show up as: -

```
ClassUnderTest_WhenDefaultConstructorUsed_SomePropertyIsNotNull
```

Comment: See a [lower answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41643793/1739931) for __net-core__.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Set `xunit.methodDisplay` in your `App.config` file.

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.methodDisplay" value="method"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Taken from http://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-xml.html

Comment: Thanks Brad!  Don't know how I missed that and curiously it's at odds with this thread: -

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/524

Comment: Note that this works only for version 2.0+ of the test runner.  See the documentation at http://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-xml.html.

Comment: I've tried setting the 'methodDisplay' config option to 'method', using the dnx runner. I followed this doc http://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html for the configuration of the dnx runner. My problem is that the name shown in the Test Explorer is still [Class].[Method], even though I expected it to be [Method]. It does seem to work as expected when running tests using the 'dnx test' command in a console though.

Comment: @Impero after you changed the `App.config`, close VS, go to `%TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions`, remove `xunit...` folders and start VS.

Comment: Not working for me. Same as Nikolaj Dam Larsen. Tried what meze suggested.

Comment: If it is not working for you, try changing the **App.config** property **"Copy to output directory" to "Copy Always"**. Did the trick for me.

Comment: For .NET Core, you need to use https://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html

However, there is an issue with copying the file: you need to make sure you actually change a test so it will fully recompile before you can see the changes! Of course, also set the JSON file's copy settings to "copy always"

Answer (score 74):

You can also add it with json.

In the root directory of your test project add a file called "xunit.runner.json".

Right-click the file, properties. Select "Copy if newer" for copy to Output directory.

Then in the file enter this json:

```js
{
    "methodDisplay": "method"
}
```

Note that you may<sup>1</sup> require to restart the IDE in order to have the changes applied.

<sup>1</sup> Visual Studio 2019 requires an IDE restart.

Comment: So much easier to read in **Test Explorer** now - great find! Worked for me in VS 2017 RTM.

Comment: It took me few visits to this answer before I realised I should upvote this. My apologies.

Comment: Please note: for me it also required to reopen project for changes to take effect.

Comment: Can I just note that this JSON method works for the Xamarin IOS Test Runner! :) the app.config one did not appear too.

Comment: It worked for me after "restart" Visual Studio 2019 Professional. I don't know why.

Comment: This was only part of the answer for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2022. For this to work, I also had to add some configuration to the .csproj file. For specifics, see the [xUnit docs on configuration](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files).