# xunit configuration not working

Tags: visual-studio, xunit

I added an `App.config` file in my unit test project as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351210/how-can-xunit-be-configured-to-show-just-the-method-name-in-the-visual-studio-20)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.methodDisplay" value="method"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But in VisualStudio, the TestExplorer still displays the full name.

I am running:

Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5

xUnit runner `[xUnit.net \[Runner: Visual Studio\] 2.1.0][2]`

Answer (score 0):

You need create xunit.runner.json in your test project
and add option **methodDisplay**
example my xunit.runner.json

```
{
   "methodDisplay": "method"
}
```

about all options you can read in https://xunit.github.io/docs/configuring-with-json.html
It's work for my VS2015