# Xunit TestNames always include namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, xunit.net, visual-studio-2017

I've a c# visual studio project in which i make tests with xunit.

Now the test explorer shows tests by their namespaces like this:

[image]

I don't want that redundant cluttering in the test names.

I know I can annotate the methods to set testnames like this:

```
public class WhenCreating : GivenConnection
    {
        [Fact(DisplayName = nameof(GivenConnection) + "." + nameof(WhenCreating ) + "." + nameof(ItAppliesFromCity))]
        public void ItAppliesFromCity()
```

But this is still very redundant as I would have to annotate each method with the same prefix. Is there any way to influence the test name generation? Like `ParentClass.SubClass.Method` ?

**update:**
To write it more expressive: i still want to have the name of the parent-class(es) in the test names. not only the method name which can be done via app.config

Comment: Please refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351210/how-can-xunit-be-configured-to-show-just-the-method-name-in-the-visual-studio-20 topic to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I don't think this duplicate as it doesn't add the parentclasses to the Test name . in the example above (GivenConnection)

Answer (score 1):

Set xunit.methodDisplay in your App.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.methodDisplay" value="method"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this doesn't add parentclass to the method names

Comment: To display parent class name, set this property to the "classAndMethod" value